# question about how to compare effect size/magnitude of odds ratios and average marginal effects

Tags: statistics, logistic-regression, marginal-effects

If in a logistic regression model with a very large sample (N=2347) I have a variable with a odds ratio of 1.51 and a average marginal effect of 0.18, but in the same model with a smaller sample (N=1412) the same variable has a odds ratio of 2.52 and average marginal effect of 0.13, is the effect size for that variable stronger in the model with the larger sample or in the model with the smaller subset sample?

Comment: This can be tested using the methodology in [Mize et al. (2019)](https://doi.org/10.1177/0081175019852763), which is available in Stata using the `suest` command.